# Julia: call a parallel loop in another file

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, distributed

Suppose I have these two files.

`test_file.jl`

```
using Distributed
function loop(N)
  @distributed for i in 1:N
          println(i)
  end
end
```

`test_file_call.jl`

```
include("test_file.jl")
loop(10)
```

If I run `julia -p 2 test_file_call.jl`, I expect the function `loop` executed on different processors, printing out 10 numbers in an arbitrary number. However, this command doesn't render anything.

I'm not sure what I did wrong? It's just a simple loop. Is it possible that I include a parallel loop in file A, write another file, B, that contains this loop, and call B to execute the parallel loop in file A? This two file structure is what I want. Is that doable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you forgot to `@sync` your loop so it exits before it actually has time to print anything.

Hence this should be:

```
function loop(N)
  @sync @distributed for i in 1:N
      println(i, " ",myid())
  end
end
```

Comment: What does `@sync` do?

Comment: `@sync`  waits until all lexically-enclosed uses of `@async`, `@spawn`, `@spawnat` and `@distributed` are complete. Have a look at https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/distributed-computing/